# Column name start with underscore (_)

Tags: sql

I am trying to use column which name is started with underscore like _name in where clause or in select clause, but can't use it. Can anyone suggest how to deal in such scenario.

Comment: `"_col1"`, or chose another name.

Comment: i Creating identifiers with names that break the rules set by your DBMS is a really bad idea, even if you can  get round it by using quotes. For example, you would need to use quotes every time you referenced this column in SQL